# why use a dictionary if a List combined with Tuples offers way more flexibility?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, tuples

new to Python, trying to learn how to use dictionaries, but honestly don't see the point, you're limited to 2 pairs whereas if I just make a list with Tuples I get far more flexibility

in the code below I made a list of superheroes, where u can look it up by
Name(Batman), Identity (Bruce Wayne) or Universe (DC)

can't do that on a dictionary (you're limited to pairs of 2) so why would I ever need a dictionary?

```
Superheroes = [('Batman','Bruce Wayne','DC'),('Spiderman','Peter Parker','Marvel'),('Superman','Clark Kent','DC'),('Ironman','Tony Stark','Marvel'),('Green Arrow','Oliver Queen','DC')]
user_selection = input()

for (name,identity,universe) in Superheroes:
  if name==user_selection or identity == user_selection or universe == user_selection:
    print('Hero:' + name + '\nSecret Identity:' + identity + '\nUniverse:'+ universe)
  else:
    continue
```

Comment: Because dictionaries don't require sequential searching.

Comment: Most uses of dictionaries don't require searching all the fields like this.

Comment: well yeah but neither would this correct?

Comment: You're doing a sequential search.

Comment: @falconflyer75: This loop checks every entry in `Superheroes`; if you have 50 million entries, that's 150 million checks (three tests for each of 50 million entries). Three `collections.defaultdict(list)` could be made, keyed by each field (one with `name` keys, one with `identity` keys, one with `universe` keys), with `list`s of matching values attached, reducing the number of checks to 3, one in each `dict`, to get all the matching entries cheaply. In this case, a database would probably work even better, and allow more complex queries, with similar performance benefits to `dict`s.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is a database.  Python includes SQLite.

Comment: ```import sqlite3``` to use it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1):

Most uses of dictionaries don't require searching for a match in both the keys and values. You design your data structure so that the item you normally need to look up is the dictionary key.

For instance, if you have data with ingredients in recipes, you would almost always be looking it up by the dish that you're cooking. So you make that the key and you can get all the ingredients with a single lookup instead of searching the entire list.

If you occasionally need to find something in the value, you can still iterate through the dictionary using `dict.entries()`. If you need to look up by different components frequently you can make multiple dictionaries that all refer to the same values using different keys.